# Export custom Sharepoint List Definitions

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on Sharepoint WSS3. Is there a way to export a custom list created via the web intarface to a list definition schema (schema.xml)?

Note: Solution Generator that is Part of the SharePoint Extension for Visual Studio is not an options as it is not supported in 64x Systems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Solution Generator](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/11/11/SharePoint-Solution-Generator-_2D00_-part-1_3A00_-create-a-site-definition-from-an-existing-site.aspx) that is Part of the [SharePoint Extension for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7BF65B28-06E2-4E87-9BAD-086E32185E68)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, kusel, but i'm working in a 64bit environment and it only supports x86

Comment: @Pistacchio : Same pain for me, How I did was to save the List as Template and rename x.stp it  to x.cab from which I can get the *.xml, then I use the Fields and others information.I know its a pain job

Answer (score 0):

[Spsource](http://www.codeplex.com/SPSource) is the tool you're looking for. It works very well and keeps all the settings of your custom list.
However, if you work in a multi-lingual environment, the .aspx forms that spsource will extract (newitem.aspx, etc.) will have hardcoded strings instead of $resources. This is easily fixed though.

SPSource also works with Content Types and List Templates. And it integrates in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

No extra software required. This will give you all you want and much more.

```
http://SERVER/SITE_PATH/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={LIST_GUID}
```